# Android : How to use javascript interface to show toast?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to show toast from a webpage showed in a webview, like in the exemple from Google : http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

I have created a class for this named : `WebAppInterface.java` :

package com.test.test;

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.test.test.R;

public class WebAppInterface extends Activity{
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and here is my main activity code called `MainActivity.java` :

```
class JsObject {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String toString() { return "injectedObject"; }
 }
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "injectedObject");
```

the page loaded by the web view contain the following code :

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

I follow exactly what is told in the Google exemple, but it dosent work... why ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "Android");
```

In javascript the variable `Android` will then be available. You were using `injectedObject` instead while registering the Javascript Interface.

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: And shouldn't `JsObject` be `WebAppInterface`?

Comment: I believe it can be any Java class object reference.

Comment: Well the name doesn't matter, but that is what the OP has called the class with `@JSInterface showToast()` in. `JSObject` does not have any useful methods.

Comment: Correct, It'll have to have the method implementation to call toast which will then be called from the JS .